# How did I lose 10 points

Tags: support, reputation

I suddenly noticed that I've lost 10 points. The reputation graph briefly says the reason as "User was removed." I've yet to get what actually happened.

Comment: Points are lost when users are deleted. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=removed